# Could anyone help me to install Intel package fortran in Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: fortran

I have downloaded the installation file from the link below but after finishing installation I am not seeing anything to open the application.
 https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compilers/choose-download

Answer (score 1):

There isn't "something to open the application". You can use the compiler from a terminal or from Xcode. Instructions are at https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-fortran-compiler-macos , but in the spirit of StackOverflow I excerpt some of them here:

Before you can use this tool, you must first set the environment variables by sourcing the environment script using the initialization utility to initialize all the tools in one step:

From a terminal session, run:

`source <install_dir>/bin/compilervars.sh intel64`
where `<install_dir>` is the directory structure containing the compiler /bin directory.

By default, the path for `<install_dir>` is`opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2020.<update number>.<packages number>/mac`
...
Use the command below to invoke the compiler from the command line.

`ifort helloworld.f90`

If you want to use Xcode, see the link above for details. Keep in mind that Xcode integration is only partial - it doesn't understand module dependencies and you can't use the debugger from within Xcode.